# Excluir de un consulta SQL junto con PHP datos de forma dinamica

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Necesito excluir de forma dinamica una consulta sql con el tipico
`SELECT * FROM agencias WHERE id_tienda != '$valor[cod]'`

Lo principal es que la variable `$valor[cod]` almacene todos los datos obtenidos a traves de los usuarios del campo donde guardo a que agencia pertenece cada uno a traves de un while y mostrarlo por un foreach

```
//Realizo la consulta a la tabla
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios"); 
$agencias = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
// Le asigno una variable a los datos obtenidos 
$cod=$row['agencia'];
$agencias[] = array('cod'=> $cod); 
}
//Ahora muestro los datos obtenidos en el foreach
foreach ($agencias as  $valor) {
echo $valor['cod'];
}
```

Con esto obtengo los datos de la siguiente manera `"agencia1 agencia2 etc.."`

Luego de esto ya estoy perdido, no encuentro como hacer que la variable $valor['cod'] me tome esos datos en la consulta sql y los excluya

Si lo hago dentro del foreach me duplica los datos y no excluye nada

Si lo hago fuera del foreach simplemente me toma la ultima recogida de datos y excluye solo ese

Si intento pasar de nuevo `$valor['cod']` a una variable igualmente no hace nada

Alguna solución? puedo intentar hace la consulta desde otra forma?

Preguntado editada:

Obteniendo el mismo resultado con el siguiente codigo

```
// Hago la consulta a la tabla de usuarios para verificar quien esta registrado en que agencia
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT agencias.nombre_tienda FROM usuarios INNER JOIN agencias ON usuarios.agencia=agencias.id_tienda"); 
$dir = array();
$cont = 0;
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
   $dir[$cont] = $row['nombre_tienda'];
   $cont++;
}
foreach ($dir as $valor) {
foreach($valor as $sub_valor) {

        array_push($dir, $sub_valor);
    }
}
$agencias_excluidas = "'".implode("','", $dir)."'";
echo $agencias_excluidas;
```

Al hacer un echo fuera de todo el codigo me arroja 'agencia1','agencia2','etc'
Para luego hacer una nueva consulta

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE agencia NOT IN ($agencias_excluidas)
```

Ya con esto podria lograr excluir los datos que aparezcan en la consulta de los usuarios

Edicion #3:
Sin necesidad de realizar algun tipo de while y foreach o incluso el implode simplemente se realiza una subconsulta en el NOT IN() seleccionando los datos que voy a buscar, ya con eso quedan excluidos los datos ya registrados

```
SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE agencia NOT IN (SELECT agencias.nombre_tienda FROM usuarios INNER JOIN agencias ON usuarios.agencia=agencias.id_tienda)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es excluir los valores del array `$agencias` en la consulta

> SELECT * FROM agencias WHERE id_tienda != ...

Para realizar esa exclusión puedes utilizar la función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) para juntar en un string los valores que necesitas excluir.

```
//Devuelve un string del estilo '"agencia1", "agencia2", "agencia3"'
$excluirAgencias = '"'.implode('", "', $agencias).'"';
```

Por último, añade ese string a la consulta junto con el `NOT IN` para que el campo id_tienda no incluya los valores de `$excluirAgencias`

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM agencias WHERE id_tienda NOT IN ('.$excluirAgencias.')';
```

Comment: Lo estoy aplicando mal o no me esta dando resultados vere que me da

Comment: Cuando le hago un echo esto no me devuelve "agencia1","agencia2", etc.. me omite las comas

Comment: @ernestojimenez podrías poner el valor del array $agencias ?

Comment: $agencias es obtenido de la consulta, es alli en donde guardare las agencias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logre, buscando me encontre con array_push y añadiendo un mejor codigo logre que me presente los datos obtenidos fuera del foreach

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT agencias.nombre_tienda FROM usuarios INNER JOIN agencias ON usuarios.agencia=agencias.id_tienda"); 
$dir = array();
$cont = 0;
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
   $dir[$cont] = $row['nombre_tienda'];
   $cont++;
}
foreach ($dir as $valor) {
foreach($valor as $sub_valor) {
        // this array_push() function adds $value to the end of $new_array.
        array_push($dir, $sub_valor);
    }
}
$agencias_excluidas = "'".implode("','", $dir)."'";
//Me devuelve 'agencia1','2','3 etc..'
```

Y para la ejecucion en mysql hice `SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE agencia NOT IN ($agencias_excluidas)`

No se si esto sea un buen metodo para omitir un grupo de usuarios en donde al registrar 1 del grupo ya los demas desaparecen pero hasta ahora es lo que tengo

Comment: tu pregunta era complicada de entender, proque planteaste una pregunta, pero en el cuerpo desarrollaste otro problema diferente, por eso te dieron una respuesta que no te sirivio.. en realidad, esto que haces ahora se puede hacer en un solo query.. si adentro el not in pones el query que usaste para sacar los valores, te va a dar el mismo resultado en una sola consulta...

Comment: Por eso yo indique si existia otro tipo de consulta, porque sinceramente no tenia mucha idea de que hacer y a ver y como quedaria el implode? porque si intento realizar lo que dices solo me arrojara 1 resultado, se supone que estos datos seran dinamicos, es decir, mientras va registrando va desapareciendo sin la necesidad de crear una tabla o borrar ciertos datos

Comment: tu pregunta es lo que llamamos un problema A->B... vos queres resolver algo de una forma y te quedas trabado con eso, cuando la solucion al problema es mas simple... podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar que es lo que queres hacer?

Comment: el query completo no te va a devolver un solo valor.. te va a devolver todos los que pedis.. y no tenes que hacer ni implode ni nada.. probalo en la base de datos...busca subconsultas de sql en google

Comment: Sinceramente desconozco de eso ya a eso no llego todavia, pero averiguare a ver que tal pero segun tu como deberia aplicar lo que me indicas? hago el query y obtengo los datos con el while, o que?

Comment: fijate y proba este query: SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE agencia NOT IN (SELECT agencias.nombre_tienda FROM usuarios INNER JOIN agencias ON usuarios.agencia=agencias.id_tienda)... aunque al select que esta entre parentesis, parece faltarle un where...

Comment: Wao, no tenia idea a que grado llegaba las sub consultas, muchas gracias todo el codigo resumido en eso

Comment: Por eso te dije lo de la pregunta A->B.. si hubieras puesto todo lo que probaste, y ademas explicado que problema querias solucionar, hubiera sido mas facil ayudarte ;)